# Is it possible to pull out a diagonal matrix from a trace operation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, trace

Suppose I have a real $m \times m$ symmetric matrix $A$, and a real $m \times m$ diagonal matrix $D$. I'm interested in finding $\operatorname{tr}(DA)$. Suppose $d$ were a scalar constant, then I know the following holds: $$\operatorname{tr}(dA) = d\cdot \operatorname{tr}(A)$$

In this case, I'm trying to think whether it's possible to pull the diagonal matrix $D$ outside of the trace operation. Since

$$\operatorname{tr}(DA) \neq \sum_{i=1}^m d_{i} \operatorname{tr}(A),$$
where $d_{i}$ is the $i$th element along the diagonal of $D$, I was thinking whether I can modify  the equation as follows so that it might hold:

$$\operatorname{tr}(DA) \overset{?}{=} \sum_{i=1}^m d_i \operatorname{tr}(B^TAB)$$

However, I'm not sure what exactly the matrix $B$ should be. Am I on the right track?

**Edit**: Also, note that $tr(D) = \sum_{i=1}^m d_i > 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Take, for example, $m=2$, $D=A=\operatorname{diag}(1,-1)$.  Then $DA=I$ so $\operatorname{tr}(DA)=2$.  However, $\operatorname{tr} D=0$ so there cannot be any formula of the form
$$
\operatorname{tr}(DA)=\operatorname{tr}(D)f(A).
$$

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. What if $tr(D)$ is strictly positive? Would it be possible then?

Comment: No.  For example, $D=\operatorname{diag}(0,1)$ gives $f(A)=A_{22}$ and $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,0)$ gives $f(A)=A_{11}$.  But you can easily get a matrix $A$ with $A_{11}\neq A_{22}$ so there could not be a possible formula in this form.